# Computing SVD in python

Tags: python, numpy, svd, decomposition

Hello everyone i am trying to compute the SVD of a matrix with numpy but i get wrong result.

I have this matrix

```
X = [[ 0  0  8]
    [ 0 23 25]
    [ 0  0  0]]
```

I am going through this code:

```
U, D, VT = np.linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
X_remake = (U @ np.diag(D ) @ VT)
```

But the result that i get is this which is obviously wrong:

```
X_remake = ([[0.00000000e+00, 1.13509861e-15, 8.00000000e+00],
            [0.00000000e+00, 2.30000000e+01, 2.50000000e+01],
            [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: What should be the correct result?

Comment: In the X_remake the correct result is the original X matrix

Comment: Have you calculated the difference between the original and the resulting matrix (element-wise)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I calculated the difference between the original and the resulting matrix but the result is still wrong. So if is this my problem what i have to do ?

Comment: But you do realize that all elements in the resulting matrix are equal to the original matrix except the middle one in the first row, and for it the difference is extremely close to zero?

Comment: No the non zero elements have big difference from zero (like 4 ), but i can't understand why, it is working with (2x2) matrix but if the matrix shape is greater than 3 x 3 it is not working.

Comment: Which two numbers have a big difference, for example?

Comment: Look at the initial post i will post the resulting matrix

Comment: if you `np.round()` your result, you will see, that there is nothing wrong with the result. As mentioned by mkrieger21, it's just floating point math.

Comment: I have already seen that, but I think that you are misinterpreting what you are seeing in the result. You think that `2.30000000e+01` is wrong because it should be `23`, don't you?

Comment: What is `X_occur`? I thought we were talking about the difference between `X` and `X_remake` so far.

Comment: Okkk, now i understood what you mean, i fixed it. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below snippet code to rebuild the input array as follow:

```
X = [[ 0 , 0 , 8]   , [ 0,23, 25]  ,  [ 0,  0,  0]]
U, D, VT = np.linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)

D=np.diag(D)    
X_remake=np.dot(U, np.dot(D, VT))    
print(X_remake)

# array([[0.00000000e+00, 1.19457349e-15, 8.00000000e+00],
#        [0.00000000e+00, 2.30000000e+01, 2.50000000e+01],
#        [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.